# Spring tiles - Open in new window

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, tiles

In my app I'm using Spring MVC + tiles + jsp + jquery.

My Spring controller returns two jsp views.

1. If result list size is 1 I return "View1".
2. If result list size is greater than 1 I return "View2".

I call to Spring controller by form submit and I work with tiles, so the returned view is shown in the body automatically.

How can I open view2 in new window? I don't know where I can configurate this.

My tiles.xml is this:

```
<definition name="view1" extends="standardLayoutTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/views/screens/view1.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="view2" template = "/WEB-INF/jsp/views/screens/view2.jsp"/>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Spring MVC Tiles** *Spring provides integration support with [apache tiles](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-jsp) framework. So we can simply manage the layout of our application.*

**Spring-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">  
   <property name="viewClass">  
       <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</value>  
  </property>  
</bean>  
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">  
    <property name="definitions"> 
    <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>  
    </list>  
    </property>  
</bean>
```

**tile.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>  
    <definition name="defaultTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">  
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />  
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />  
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp" />  
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />  
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />  
    </definition>       
</tiles-definitions>
```

**view.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<tiles:insertDefinition name="defaultTemplate">
    <tiles:putAttribute name="body">
        <body> . . . .  </body>
    </tiles:putAttribute>   
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```

**layout.jsp**

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;        padding: 0;
    width:100%;       height:100%;
}
#container {
    width:100%;
}    
#header {
    width:100%;           height:5%;
    position:fixed;       background-color:#A0A0A0 ;
}
#sidebar {
    top: 5%;          position:fixed;
    left:0;           height:90%;
    width:13%;        background-color:#D0D0D0 ;
}
#content {
    top:5%;            position:fixed;
    right:0;           height: 90%;
    width: 87%;        overflow:auto;
    background-color: white;
}
#footer {
    bottom:0;          position:fixed;      
    width:100%;        height:5%;    
    background-color:#A0A0A0 ;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"> <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"> </div>
    <div id="sidebar"><tiles:insertAttribute name="menu">   </div>
    <div id="content"><tiles:insertAttribute name="body">   </div>
    <div id="footer"> <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"> </div>
</div>
```